# How to continue the effect of "setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" after "endlocal"?

Tags: batch-file

Here are two batch files : 1.bat, setenv.bat 
**1.bat:** 
    `call setenv.bat`
    `echo %var%`
**setenv.bat:**    
    `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`
    `...` 
    `for ... do (`
        `if ... (`
        `set var=!other!`
    `)`
    `)`
    `endlocal`
delayed expansion is needed in `setenv.bat` for some reason. `setenv.bat` is used to set some environment variables, which used in other files, `1.bat` here. 
But even if `var` is set in `setenv.bat` correctly, `1.bat` still uses the old value of `var`: Say `var=old` before calling `setenv.bat`, and `setenv.bat` change the value of `var` to `new`, but the output of `1.bat` is still `old`, which I need it to be `new`.

**Any way to gain the effect of delayed expansion without localizing the in-course modification?**

Comment: It depends on the possible content of `var`. For trivial content the solution from Magoo works, for content with special characters the solution of Rafael is better, but there exists more complex strings which need more complex solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very end of `setenv.bat`:

```
...
endlocal&set "var=%var%"&set "var2=%var2%"
```

Comment: Yep +1. The tunneling , but would prefer brackets after the first `&`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `FOR /F` to keep your variable:

**setenv.bat:**

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set other=new
...
for /f "delims=" %%V in (""!other!"") do (
 endlocal
 for ... do (
  if ... (
   set var=%%~V
  )
 )
)
```